# Understanding transition.js complex function check .

Tags: jquery

Hey guys i saw the below function in transition.js

```
function transitionEnd() {
    var el = document.createElement('bootstrap')

    var transEndEventNames = {
      WebkitTransition : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
      MozTransition    : 'transitionend',
      OTransition      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
      transition       : 'transitionend'
    }

    for (var name in transEndEventNames) {
      if (el.style[name] !== undefined) {
        return { end: transEndEventNames[name] }
      }
    }
```

now i understand most part of the function , but once i look at the for in loop , there is a little confusion i have. I do understand, the for in loop , what i don't understand thought is the if condition , i see that its checking if `el.style[name]` is `NOT EQUAL TO` `undifined` , But my question is WHERE IS `el.style[name]` not equal to undefined ?? i just want to understand the below line :

```
if (el.style[name] !== undefined) {
```

i understand **what** it is checking for . but i don't understand **where**  it is checking for .

I do know that i am missing something really simple maybe . but i have been on this for quite a while and still can't understand this line.

the line can also be found on git , [Line 27](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/transition.js#L27).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What it is doing is to finding out what is the supported `transition end` event name to be used.

How is it doing it? by looking at the supported `transition` css property name. As you know an all [elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) has a [style property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style). If you look at the style object of an element you can find that all the supported style names are listed there with `''`(empty string) as its value.

So here `transEndEventNames` holds the names of 4 `transition` css key, and we are checking which of this is supported, if any one of those key is supported then the `style` object will have a empty string as its value, if the css attribute is not supported then that will not be present in the style object so `style[name]` will return `undefined`

Comment: @ArunPJohnny will the undefiened properties returned differ in each browser ?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean

Comment: @ArunPJonny ,  check this fiddle and check my comment http://jsfiddle.net/d8bxv7s1/

Comment: `el.style[name]` would usually be used when you would want to check a CSS property not an event , `webkitTransitionEnd`,
  `transitionend`,
     `oTransitionEnd otransitionend`,
       `transitionend` , are all events not CSS properties .

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik but we are checking `var name in transEndEventNames` then `el.style[name]` so `name` is the property keys in `transEndEventNames` which are `WebkitTransition`, `MozTransition`, `OTransition`, `transition` so they are css properties